# can i show gps location pop message again?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

i have application in this application i want to display sorting data using user's location.

but first time when  i open application it ask me for allow or not allow for location.

i press don't allow. this never ask me again for location how can i rest this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya you can do this by going on this way

settings >> general >> reset >>Reset Location warnings

by this doing it will ask again same warning . may be this help you

Comment: ya this is working but how can i do this same thing by code . by this all location warning reset i want to reset only for one application.

Answer (score 0):

First option : Then you had to use a button in your app where user can update his location again by pressing the button.

Second Option : Call update location method after some time interval to get the location of the user.

Comment: it going in a "didFinishWithResult" becouse i select dont allow to use user location. i want to enable this thing. how can i do this ?

Comment: Then in your "didFinishWithResult", again call update location. If the latitude and longitude are nil then prompt user with the alert that the location is needed for the application to work properly and when user press the button on alertview update the location.

Comment: how can i show that alert again ? i want exact that code by which i can show alert again ..

Comment: inside your didfinshwithresult, check wether the latitude and longitude variables wheer you storing the coordinates are nil or not. If they are nil then show alewrt and upon dismissing alert get the loaction of the user.The code was exact as you had at the start of the application to get the locationof user.